# PHP Regex Match Specific Pattern between Quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, strpos

I have strings with the following pattern:

adfadfadfadfadfadfafdadfa"externalId":"UCEjBDKfrqQI4TgzT9YLNT8g"afadfadfafadfdaffzfzfzxf

Basically, I need to find "externalId" and extract it's value in between the quotes that follow. The length of the value can change so it needs to be everything inside the two quotes. In this case the desired outcome is to return:

```
 UCEjBDKfrqQI4TgzT9YLNT8g
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$test = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/c/GhostTownLiving');
$test = htmlentities($test);

if (strpos($test, 'externalId') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

I tried Advanced HTML Dom but since these externalId property inside these YouTube channel pages are loaded via javascript I couldn't target it successfully.

Basically, i'm using htmlentities to return the code and then I'd like to extract the externalId value.

How can I write a regex pattern to match that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse out the whole JSON, then decode it and traverse though to what value you're after.

```
<?php
$test = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/c/GhostTownLiving');

// match the ytInitialData JSON
preg_match('#var ytInitialData = {(.*?)};</script>#', $test, $matches);

// add back the surounding {}'s, and parse
$ytInitialData = json_decode('{'.$matches[1].'}');

// then you have that massive object easily accessible
echo $ytInitialData->metadata->channelMetadataRenderer->externalId; // UCEjBDKfrqQI4TgzT9YLNT8g
```

Though, if you can obtain that from the API its friendlier then scraping

Comment: thanks! yea I haven't found a way to extract the externalId through the API itself yet

Comment: np, just be aware that file_get_contents sends `php` as user agent, many requests might get your server or home IP blocked, I not sure their policy, prob be better to use curl with random user agent and fully mock the headers a browser would send, though I bet they still have tools/strategies to detect its not a browser as curl/fgc wont be downloading any other assets

Comment: good point, I have some proxies I can put to use ;)

Comment: One of you please take the responsibility of cleaning up this question so that the title and question body are clear, specific , and searchable.